# Relationship between $\theta$ functions and number fields.

Tags: number-theory, abelian-varieties, theta-functions, l-functions

I'm trying to have a clear picture of the relationship of theta functions and $L$-functions, and the geometric objects they relate to.

Firstly, I know that $\theta$-functions arise as sections of line bundles on abelian varieties. So if you take a lattice $\Lambda$ in $V=\mathbb{C}^g$ and a polarization $H$ (i.e a hermitian form on $V$ such that $E=Im(H)$ is definite positive and integral on $\Lambda$) you get an abelian variety $X=V/\Lambda$ and a class of line bundles $L(H, \bullet)$. If you specify a quasi-character of $H$, then you get a well definied line bundle $L$ on $X$ whose 1st chern class is $E$. So far this is clear.

From the data of $\Lambda$ alone, you get a family of $\theta$ functions, which correspond to all sections of all the line bundles on $X$. Basically $\theta$-functions are paramterized by a lattice, a polarization and a quasi-character. You can also parametrize them by an element in the Siegel half space, a polarization and a quasi-character.

Now on the other hand $L$-functions arise as Mellin Transform of $\theta$-functions (up to Euler/Gamma-factors). For instance the Riemann Zeta function satsifies $$\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(s/2)\zeta(s)=Mel(\theta(it)-1, s)$$
with $\theta(z)=\sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}}e^{i\pi m^2z}$ the Jacobi theta function.

Of course the term $it$ in $Mel(\theta(it)-1, s)$ makes me think that $it$ lives in $\mathbb{H}$ the upper half plane, but I don't think that should be relevant because the variable $t$ is the one integrated in the Mellin transform so it's not a fixed parameter that I could interpret as corresponding to some lattice.

So my (rather blurry) question is : what is the relationship between the "abelian variety" picture of theta functions, and the zeta functions of number field arrising as Mellin transforms of the same $\theta$-functions.

The naive picture I have in mind (which is probably not true) is the following.

If you take $k$ a number field, its ring of integer gives you via the canonnical embedding a lattice $\Lambda$ in some vector space $\mathbb{C}^g$ (obvisouly there are some problems already, as the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^{s+t}$ has no reason to be even in general). The abelian variety $X=\mathbb{C}^g/\Lambda$ has a polarization (coming from the trace on the number field ?) and thus a line bundle, unique up to translation which has a section defined by a $\theta$ function, such that $\zeta_k$ is essentially the Mellin transform of that $\theta$-function.

Now what is wrong with that picture? How far is it from what actually happens? And what is the real picture?

I've seen $\theta$-functions in the context of $L$-functions, parametrized by all sorts of parameters, e.g Neukirch writes $$\theta_\Gamma(a,b,z)=\sum_{g\in \Gamma}N(a+g)e^{i\pi((a+g)z, a+g)+2i\pi(b,g)}$$
in this case can I interpret $\theta_\Gamma(a,b,z)$ as a section on some line bundle on $\mathbb{C}^d/\Gamma$ ?

I feel like those $(a,b)$ should be some $(H,\alpha)$ for some "natural" $(H,\alpha)$, am I completely mistaken here?

Comment: Can you expand on the $\theta$ you wish to associate to $\Bbb{C}^g/\Lambda$ ? For non quadratic-imaginary number fields we need $\theta$ functions of several variable, change of variable $(t_1,\ldots,t_N) = (e^{v_1},\ldots,e^{v_N})$ the "Mellin transform" is $f(s)= \int_{\Bbb{R}^N/U} (\prod_{n=1}^N e^{v_n s}) \theta(i e^{v_1},\ldots,i e^{v_N}) d^N v$ where $ U=\sum_{j=1}^J \Bbb{Z} \log u_j$ is the image of the unit group $O_k^\times$ and quotienting by $U$ is intended to kill $O_k^\times$.

Comment: For Neukrich the $a$ variable is intended to be set to $0$, it is there for the functional equation in the same way that it is the Fourier series of $\vartheta_t(a)=\sum_n e^{-\pi t(a+n)^2} = \sum_k t^{-1/2}e^{-\pi k^2/t} e^{2i \pi ak}$ which tells us the functional equation of $\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(s/2)\zeta(s) = \frac12\int_0^\infty t^{s/2-1}(\vartheta_t(0)-1)dt$.

Comment: Well I wouldn't know exactly what $\theta$ I would want to associate, I'm thinking something like a section of a line bundle on $\mathbb{C}^g/j(O_k)$ where $j$ is the canonical embedding.

Comment: What baffles me is that these $\theta$-functions which are associated to number fields via their zeta functions, look a lot like the theta functions associated to line bundles on abelian variety, and I feel like there should be some connection between the two of them. But maybe they're not really related and I should only consider $\theta$-functions for number fields as ad-hoc functions?

Comment: In the case of imaginary quadratic fields, can we say something?
I mean in this case $O_k$ is a lattice in $\mathbb{C}$ and thus defines a CM elliptic curve $E/\mathbb{C}$. Can we find a line bundle on it, such that $\zeta_k(s)$ is naturally $Mel(\theta, s)$ for $\theta$ defining a section of this line bundle.

Comment: " section of a line bundle on Cg/j(Ok) " isn't a theta function, can you define them really...

Comment: Yeah sure, I can give you a reference as defining them in the comments would take long, you can look at beauville's paper https://math.unice.fr/~beauvill/pubs/thetaon.pdf

Comment: In particular you can look at proposition 2.2, where the space of sections of a line bundle on a complex torus is canonically identified with a space of theta functions, and such theta functions are explicitely determined in the paragraph 3.4.

Comment: If you look at the Riemann theta function whose expression is given on page 113 of Beauville's paper, it is very close to the expression that Neukirch gives and that i wrote in my message (sorry I'm on my cellphone, so it's hard to use tex).

Comment: Are you saying that those 2 kinds of theta functions, the ones appearing for zeta functions of number fields, and the ones appearing for sections of line bundles on abelian varieties have no relationship with one another beside sharing the same notation?